# Inserting a foreign key when creating an object with a foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i cant really understand what is the problem i have this model :

```
class Upload_files(models.Model): #uploaded files(for approval) are stored here
file=models.FileField(upload_to=""+strftime("%j", gmtime())+"/")
cont = models.ForeignKey(Contractor)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.file.name
```

and the form :

```
class uploadFile(forms.ModelForm):
file = forms.FileField(label=(u'file'))

cont = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="cont",
                             queryset=Contractor.objects.all(),
                             required = False
                             )
```

and in the method that i create in it the object :

```
cont = Contractor.objects.get(id=contractor_id)
file = Upload_files.objects.create(file=file,cont=cont)
file.save()
```

and thats the error that i get :

```
shoghlanah_upload_files has no column named cont_id
```

i cant really understand whats wrong with my code so please any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either delete your database and recreate it using `syncdb`, or setup [`south`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#starting-off) and run a migration on your current database.